# Getting geolocation and Sending an Ajax Request in componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, fetch-api

I'm trying to call a weather API with coordinates recieved from the user's computer using navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()

My problem is I'm having trouble figuring out the right way to do this given everything is running asyncronously. Then, I thought I came up with a decent work-around using componentDidMount(), but unfortunately it didn't work.

Here's my [codepen](https://codepen.io/HuntingHawk/pen/eyvVjg?editors=0011) (sans API key)

And here's the code:

```
state = {
        data: "Please wait while you're weather is loading...",
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.state.hasOwnProperty('uri') ?
            fetch(this.state.uri).then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => this.setState({
                data: {
                    tempString: data.current_observation.temperature_string,
                    realTemp: data.current_observation.feelslike_string,
                    skyImg: data.current_observation.icon_url.substring(0, 4) + 's' + data.current_observation.icon_url.substring(4),
                    location: data.current_observation.display_location.full,
                    temp_f: data.current_observation.temp_f,
                }
            }))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err.message))
        : navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos) => {
            this.setState({
                uri: "https://api.wunderground.com/api/{API GOES HERE}/conditions/q/" + pos.coords.latitude.toString() + "," + pos.coords.longitude.toString() + ".json"
            })
            console.log(this.state.uri)
        })
    }
```

My understanding of how everything is running is as follows:

1. Initial component renders
2. componentDidMount() is called and takes a look at the if statement
3. can't find the URI property, so starts the getCurrentPosition() call, setting state with the new URI property (to my knowledge, this.setState should trigger a re-render, and then...)
4. componentDidMount() runs again, but this time finds the URI property
5. for some unknown reason, fetch() isn't running

Though I'm not sure, my best guess is although there is now URI property, by time the new componentDidMount() runs, the program is still in the process of figuring out what to set it as. But I might be completely wrong. I could've also created an infinite loop where componentDidMount() never sees a URI property and continuously re-renders.

Comment: why would componentDidMount run more than once?  it just runs once, when the component is mounted.

Comment: Thanks for that! I completely overlooked the fact that componentDidMount on the initial mounting, and not on a re-render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @brub said: componentDidMount doesn't run more than once, no matter how much the ui is updated. I ended up using componentDidUpdate as a solution. Here's the code now:

```
    state = {
        data: "Please wait while you're weather is loading...",
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos) => {
            this.setState({
                uri: "https://api.wunderground.com/api/{API GOES HERE}/conditions/q/" + pos.coords.latitude.toString() + "," + pos.coords.longitude.toString() + ".json"
            })
        })
    }
    componentDidUpdate() {
        fetch(this.state.uri).then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => this.setState({
            data: {
                tempString: data.current_observation.temperature_string,
                realTemp: data.current_observation.feelslike_string,
                skyImg: data.current_observation.icon_url.substring(0, 4) + 's' + data.current_observation.icon_url.substring(4),
                location: data.current_observation.display_location.full,
                temp_f: data.current_observation.temp_f,
            }
        }))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err.message))
    }
```